# Django rest framework how to pass authorizing token in nextjs post request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, next.js, fetch-api

How to pass django authorization token in nextjs axois. I tried this for pass authorization token but getting 404 error.

```
let token = "Token 8736be9dba6ccb11208a536f3531bccc686cf88d"
await axios.post(url,{
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
          contact_name:contact_name,contact_email:contact_email,contact_body:contact_body,
          
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're sending the bearer token the correct way. Try removing "Token" from the token variable and it should work

Correct code:

```
let token = "8736be9dba6ccb11208a536f3531bccc686cf88d"
await axios.post(url,{
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
          contact_name:contact_name,contact_email:contact_email,contact_body:contact_body,
          
        })
```